# Is tan(y) = x + C, the same as Y = x/tan + C/tan?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, trigonometry

Alright so the title says it all.

I am working on a method called Separation of Variables with differential equations. The original problem was Y'= cos^2y.

I am wondering since I was trying to get "Y" all alone and move the tangent to the other side if that was acceptable or is there no way of doing it?

Comment: Absolutely not. What even is "tan", without any arguments?

Comment: @MattiP. Tangent

Comment: Please study functions and inverse functions before doing anything like this. The logic is completely wrong. The only correct approach is
$$\tan{y} = x+C \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad y = \tan^{-1}{(x+C)}$$ where $\tan^{-1}{}$ is the inverse tangent function.

Comment: @MattiP. That's why I was asking...

Comment: Ahh okay, thank you that cleared it up!! @MattiP. I completely forgot it was like that. I am very bad with PreCalculus. Not very strong in it.

Comment: @MattiP. May I ask, why is everyone down voting this? I was simply asking a question, I don't know why everyone is down voting...

Comment: Well, I wasn't the one voting down, so it's hard to say. Perhaps they see this as a naive error and therefore, a naive post.

Comment: @MattiP. Ahh okay, thank you for clarifying and for your help. It was very helpful.

Comment: Warning ... $\tan^{-1}$ does not mean $\frac{1}{\tan}$ ... instead, $\tan^{-1}$ is a (confusing to students, such as Adan) notation for $\arctan$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have divided each side by $\tan(x)$. Sadly, this isn't valid, for a couple of reasons:

- Less importantly, for some $x$, $\tan(x)=0$: this would amount to division by zero.
- You didn't include the argument of the tangent functions, i.e. the $(x)$ bit. This is important to be sure what your variables are.
- More importantly, you seem to have thought that

$$\tan(y)/\tan(y) = Y$$

The latter is wrong, because dividing something by itself should give you $1$.

---

So what should you do?

My recommendation: take the arctangent of both sides; it is the inverse function of tangent. Thus,

$$\arctan(\tan(y)) = y$$

Then, doing this, you'd get

$$y = \arctan(x+C)$$

Comment: thank you, I understand it, I can recall. What I'm wondering now, if that is an acceptable answer to have Y equal with my Separation of Variables problem?

Comment: I personally don't see a problem with it.

Comment: Alright, thank you! I was just making sure I was doing this correctly.